# Can not uninstall "ndiswrapper-dkms"

Tags: apt, dpkg, ndiswrapper

I keep getting the same thing while removing it or updating. It doesn't move. I done `remove`,`purge`,`reinstall` and nothing seems to get past this point.

```
jimbow@ShitToaster ~ $ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ndiswrapper-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ndiswrapper-dkms*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 767 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 290881 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ndiswrapper-dkms (1.60-3~ubuntu16.04.2) ...
```

**EDIT**

I did `apt-cache policy ndiswrapper-dkms` to see if it's installed and I got this

```
ndiswrapper-dkms:
  Installed: 1.60-3~ubuntu16.04.2
  Candidate: 1.60-3~ubuntu16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.60-3~ubuntu16.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.59-6 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: Is the result the same with: `sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper*` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Wonderful hostname.

Comment: How do you know it's still installed?

Comment: @chili555 its the same thing for every kinda removal with `ndiswrapper`.

Comment: @NonnyMoose I can't install or update anything with that installed being broken. I can not even install the program via .deb